# VBA search for specific number with leading zero

Tags: vba, excel

Need to distinguish between 033 and 000033 (for example).

I want to change any 033 to 10033 and leave any other "033" untouched.

Comment: Use the Range().Text property to return the value as it is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you asking..but I think here is what might be able to help you

```
If trim(strValue)="033" then
    strValue = Replace(strValue,"033","10033")
End If
```